# Find all Stock In and Stock Out dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've function which returns Inventory Qty day-by-day of a given ItemCode like:

```
ItemCode | InventoryDate | InventoryQty
---------------------------------------
Product1 | 2019-07-05    |   12
Product1 | 2019-07-12    |   3
Product1 | 2019-08-03    |   0
Product1 | 2019-08-15    |   7
Product1 | 2019-08-29    |   0
Product1 | 2019-09-02    |   9
```

and more.

I need to find dates when InventoryQty is zero and then when again in stock. But in all time.
In this example:

```
ItemCode | StockOut   |  StockIn   |  StockOut  |   StockIn
------------------------------------------------------------
Product1 | 2019-08-03 | 2019-08-15 | 2019-08-29 | 2019-09-02
```

For Product1, it returns 2 times InventoryQty equals zero but for ProductX can maybe returns 3 or more.

I need your help, how can write a select condition?

Comment: So, are you expecting `2*{number of times out of stock}+1` columns in your final dataset? I'd reconsider that if so and consider a normalise dataset. What have you tried so far to get the results you're after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @Inventor TABLE (ItemCode VARCHAR(10), InventoryDate DATE,  InventoryQty INT)
INSERT @Inventor VALUES
('Product1', '2019-07-05', 12),
('Product1', '2019-07-12', 3 ),
('Product1', '2019-08-03', 0 ),
('Product1', '2019-08-15', 7 ),
('Product1', '2019-08-29', 0 ),
('Product1', '2019-09-02', 9 )


SELECT StIn.ItemCode, StOut.InventoryDate StockOut , StIn.InventoryDate StockIn FROM @Inventor StOut   
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Inventor S WHERE StOut.ItemCode = S.ItemCode 
                    AND S.InventoryDate > StOut.InventoryDate
                    AND S.InventoryQty > 0
                 ORDER BY S.InventoryDate   
                    ) StIn   
WHERE StOut.InventoryQty = 0
```

Result:

```
ItemCode   StockOut   StockIn
---------- ---------- ----------
Product1   2019-08-03 2019-08-15
Product1   2019-08-29 2019-09-02
```

Comment: This is by far the better way to do it since n number of columns is just a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Return the values in separate rows, rather than separate columns.  I would just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(InventoryQty) over (partition by ItemCode order by InventoryDate) as prev_InventoryQty
      from t
     ) t
where prev_InventoryQty = 0 or InventoryQty = 0;
```

You can combine these into a single row for each outage -- but your question doesn't specify what to do if there are multiple `0`s in a row.